# Recover methods from saved Javascript obect

Tags: javascript

If I have a class declaration in Javascript with a simple method as so:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    sum() {
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
```

I can then create an object and call its `sum()` method.

```
var bar = new Foo(2, 5); // {"a": 2, "b": 5}
var total = bar.sum(); // 7
```

I can also store this object (`bar`) in a database or local storage by first converting it to a string:

```
localStorage.savedBar = JSON.stringify(bar); // "{\"a\": 2, \"b\": 5}"
```

However, when I retrieve it, I can no longer access its methods.

```
var retrievedBar = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedBar); // {"a": 2, "b": 5}
var secondTotal = retrievedBar.sum(); // retrievedBar.sum is not a function!
```

This is really annoying, as it means that I would have to reconstruct any class objects. I have to say,

```
var goodRetrievedBar = new Foo(retrievedBar.a, retrievedBar.b);
var goodSecondTotal = goodRetrievedBar.sum(); // 7
```

which might seem fine for this scenario, but as soon as I even think about more deeply nested  data structures, I very quickly enter the land of `for` loops and complex logic for a seemingly simple task. Also, if I wanted to make changes to my class in the future:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(a, b, c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        if (typeof c !== 'undefined') {
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
    sum() {
        if (this.c) {
            return this.a + this.b + this.c;
        }
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
```

I would also have to update my parsing code to support the additional property, `c`, when the changes I made to the class wouldn't require me to make any other changes in my code.

Is there an easier way to force an object to assimilate itself into a class somehow? What is the standard way to deal with this in a simple and effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions generally can't be serialized and deserialized in all cases (due to closures), nor can objects with internal prototypes (other than `Object.prototype`) have those prototypes reflected after deserialization.

What you *can* do is serialize the own-properties of the instance, then when deserializing, use `Object.create` so that the internal prototype of the new instance is the class prototype.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(a, b, c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        if (typeof c !== 'undefined') {
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
    sum() {
        if (this.c) {
            return this.a + this.b + this.c;
        }
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
const f = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
const stringified = JSON.stringify(f);

const retrievedInstance = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Object.assign(retrievedInstance, JSON.parse(stringified));
console.log(retrievedInstance.sum());
```

Note that this approach won't work if you have anything stored in *closures* somewhere in the original object rather than in *properties* on the instance.